# Do Chrome extensions have access to local storage?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

Is it possible to store data in a way that will be accessible after a browser restart in the context of a chrome extension?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Even simpler than that:

To read:

```
    var myStoredValue = localStorage["TheKeyToMyStoredValue"];
```

To write:

```
    localStorage["TheKeyToMyStoredValue"] = myNewValueToStore;
```

To get rid of:

```
    delete localStorage["TheKeyToMyStoredValue"];
```

Comment: You sir are a level 99 druid and saint.

Comment: great answer. just note that this won't work with content scripts. I was confused until I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15466494/4926817)

Answer (score 21):

Yes, it is. Going over a full walkthrough of how to do this would probably exceed the length of a reasonable StackOverflow answer, so I'll refer you to **[this very extensive tutorial](http://www.rajdeepd.com/articles/chrome/localstrg/LocalStorageSample.htm)** by Rajdeep Dua.

The relevant code would look like this:

```
// Store item in local storage:
function setItem(key, value) {
  try {
    log("Storing [" + key + ":" + value + "]");
    window.localStorage.removeItem(key);      // <-- Local storage!
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);  // <-- Local storage!
  } catch(e) {
    log("Error inside setItem");
    log(e);
  }
  log("Return from setItem" + key + ":" +  value);
}

// Gets item from local storage with specified key.
function getItem(key) {
  var value;
  log('Retrieving key [' + key + ']');
  try {
    value = window.localStorage.getItem(key);  // <-- Local storage!
  }catch(e) {
    log("Error inside getItem() for key:" + key);
  log(e);
  value = "null";
  }
  log("Returning value: " + value);
  return value;
}

// Clears all key/value pairs in local storage.
function clearStrg() {
  log('about to clear local storage');
  window.localStorage.clear(); // <-- Local storage!
  log('cleared');
}

function log(txt) {
  if(logging) {
    console.log(txt);
  }
}
```

Comment: The tutorial's link is broken, but the example still exists. Here is the example of the tutorial https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hmbpgbeiphknbkjjfppodijapijlpkkc

Comment: This API does a pretty good job as well:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html
It also allows you to sync the data to your profile

Answer (score 7):

Chrome also supports the HTML5 [Web Database](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/) spec. This gives you a local SQL database, so you can do more complex things than simply storing name/value pairs in Local Storage.

Answer (score 5):

The current chrome version has local storage.

I have used it myself. You can use modernizr to detect whether the browser supports it or not.
I have written a solution for a client where I do a fallback to cookie if no local storage exists, but this shouldn't be a problem for extensions.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays it might be better to use [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)
chrome.storage is asynchronous, which makes it faster and localStorage is limited to 5MB.

Comment: "which makes it faster" _\[citation needed\]_

Comment: As specified [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage) by chrome devs, bulk non-blocking reads and writes operations are faster than the blocking and serial localStorage API.

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

there are already some great answers here, but note that if you decide to use a content script in your extension, that content script won't have access to localStorage. therefore [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) is a good alternative.

Comment: _Technically_ it will have access to `localStorage` - it will be the local storage of the domain the content script is running on (shared with the page itself).