# cookie or localStorage with chrome extensions

Tags: cookies, google-chrome, local-storage

I've read all the other q's here regarding the topic but couldn't solve my problem.
I'm setting on my website the email of the user in the localStorage and i want to retrieve it in the extension.

```
localStorage.setItem("user", "andrei.br92@gmail.com" );
```

But when i try to receive it with the chrome extension it fails to do so

```
value = localStorage.getItem("user");
```

Which way is easier ? cookies localstorage ? im not pretentious

Comment: When you try to retrieve the value, what do you get -- undefined, or null?  Also -- what page/file are you using to store the item and what page/file are you using to retrieve the item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please see this:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication

Content scripts are run in a separate JavaScript world, which means the content script's `localStorage` is different from the website's `localStorage`. The only thing the two share is the DOM, so you'll need to use DOM nodes/events to communicate.

Answer (score 6):

Use `chrome.storage.local` instead of `localstorage`. Content scripts using `chrome.storage` see the same thing that the extension page sees. More at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html

Answer (score 2):

Please see the information on [Chrome content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html). I'm betting you fell into the same initial trap that I did -- trying to read localStorage from an page-injected script, yes?

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to use cookies when localstorage can do. That is because

- Cookies can be accessed/modified through background page only.
- Cookies are stored in context of a url/domain and not extension. So you will have to store a cookie for every domain that you wish to operate upon.
- With every HttpRequest all the cookies associated with corresponding url/domain gets transmitted to server, so in effect you will be adding overhead to user's requests.)