# JS how to store data on Client from server script

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a php script that returns employee details e.g name and address in json encoded format.

I loop through the data returned and print only their names out on a list, not needing to display other data on initial page load.

```
$.post( "./php/getEmployees.php",function( data ) {
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
    $("#list").append('<li><a href="#section2">'+value.title+'</a></li>');
});
},"json");
```

Now I will have a list of employee names on screen for the user to see.

If they were to click on an employee I want to display the rest of their details that was returned in the `getEmployees.php` script.

How would I store data from my script to be accessed later?

Comment: Use localStore http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404813/how-to-view-or-edit-localstorage

Comment: The `value` object will giver you the details which you can append as a div with details. Make this div invisible initially then when they click on Employee you can enable this div.

Comment: If its not a huge list of employees, you can store it in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

example of usage:

```
var person = {name:'some name', contact: {phone:'xxxxxxxx', address: 'yyyyyyyy'}}
// store
localStorage.setItem('person', JSON.stringify(person))
// retrieve
var myPerson = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('person'))
console.log(myPerson.contact)

// Output:
// Object {phone: "xxxxxxxx", address: "yyyyyyyy"}
```