# How to add values in localstorage in vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to have a `laravel passport authentication`, `generating access tokens` and storing them to `localStorage`, I'm able to get the access token but while placing it into localStorage I'm unable to fetch the value, while doing so I'm implementing something like this:

```
axios.post('/oauth/token', postData).then(response => {
    if(response.status === 200)
    {
        authUser.access_token = response.data.access_token;
        authUser.refresh_token = response.data.refresh_token;
        console.log(authUser);
        window.localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(authUser))
        console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('authUser'))
    }
})
```

As I said I'm implementing in predefined laravel so the resources I'm using is defaults. Do I need to add anything more? like `vue-resource`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember to parse the value, since you used `JSON.strigify`, the following should work:

```
// Saving
localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(authUser));

// Fetching
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authUser'))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but when I inspect the application in chrome, I'm unable to view in my application local storage, is it hidden?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404813/how-to-view-or-edit-localstorage

Comment: Yes the same place, i'm unable to view any values

Comment: Sorry, if the linked post didn't help then I can't assist you any further.