# Javascript variable not being appended to HTML element even though the variable has a value

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to append a javascript variable within one of my html tags however it does not work at all even though the variable has a value. I am grabbing the variable through local storage so I am not sure if it is because of that or not? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      <li class="sidebar-brand">
        <h3 id="welcome"></h3>=
        <script>
          var name = localStorage.getItem('name')
          document.getElementById("welcome").value = name;
        </script>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Overview</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Events</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You open a P tag and you close a h3 tag, this looks like a typo

Comment: Apologies, supposed to be a h3 tag

Comment: How is this value being stored in the localStorage?

Comment: Here you can find iformation how to view or edit your local storage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404813/how-to-view-or-edit-localstorage

Comment: @CalvinNunes The problem exists even without the call to `localStorage`

Comment: The variable does have a value as i console out it, setting it like this for now :         localStorage.setItem('name', "John");

Comment: but you are not setting it, you are just getting it... `localStorage.getItem("name")` tries to find a "variable" stored under name of "name" and returns it string value. If you never use `localStoage.setItem("name", "some value")` it will never exist

Comment: I am setting it in another html page, the problem isnt that the variable does not exist as I am able to see the variable

Comment: so use `.textContent = name` or `.innerHTML =  name`... not `.value = name`. `value` are just for input like elements

Comment: Yup that was the issue, I got confused between innerHtml and value, totally forgot value is just for inputs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the name variable is definitely set use `.innerHTML` instead of `.value`

Comment: That worked, thanks for the quick solution!

Comment: Thats no problem

Answer (score 0):

Try innerHTML

> The innerHTML property sets or returns the HTML content (inner HTML)
>   of an element.

```
<script>
var name = localStorage.getItem('name')
document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML= name;
</script>
```

Comment: Please add a bit of explanation. Just dropping code is discouraged.