# How to clear localStorage on button click

Tags: javascript, function, local-storage

I followed a tutorial on Youtube about localStorage and everything went fine. After that I tried to mess around with the concepts and wanted to add a button to remove the localStorage (id ="btnClear").

Now I've tried everything but it doesnt let me remove the storage. I think its because I declared the constants inside the function and I might have to store them somewhere outside and stringify the input. But can I clear the localStorage somehow even in this scenario?

```
<body>
<content>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Insert Data</legend>
        <input type="text" id="inpKey" placeholder="Insert Key.." />
        <input type="text" id="inpValue" placeholder="Insert Value.." />
        <button type="button" id="btnInsert">Insert</button>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Local Storage</legend>
        <div id="lsOutput"></div>
        <br />
        <button type="button" id="btnClear">Clear</button>
      </fieldset>
    </content>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const inpKey = document.getElementById("inpKey");
    const inpValue = document.getElementById("inpValue");
    const btnInsert = document.getElementById("btnInsert");
    const lsOutput = document.getElementById("lsOutput");
    const btnClear = document.getElementById("btnClear");

    btnInsert.onclick = function () {
      const key = inpKey.value;
      const value = inpValue.value;

      if (key && value) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
        location.reload();
      }
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
      const key = localStorage.key(i);
      const value = localStorage.getItem(key);
      lsOutput.innerHTML += `${key}: ${value}`;
    }

    //BUTTON CLEAR

    btnClear.onclick = function () {
      localStorage.clear();
    };
  </script>
```

Comment: does btnClear.onclick function called, did you check that?

Comment: try to put it(script) in document.ready

Comment: please, have a look at my answer, so you would save some typing time!

Answer (score 2):

Check your local storage in the browser. Your code actually **does clear the localStorage**. What you are missing is to update your UI. Replace your Button clear code with that:

```js
btnClear.onclick = function () {
   localStorage.clear();
   if(localStorage.length === 0)
      lsOutput.innerHTML = "";
};
```

Here is a tutorial how you check your local storage in chrome for example: [How to view or edit localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404813/how-to-view-or-edit-localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here, I have update all you code from HTML to JS.

You can test it [on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/UtmostCreator/ju5pkxrf/5/) as stackoverflow will throw this error:

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 37,
  "colno": 33
}
```

#### Also, It is better to use `document.addEventListener` with most of your events (as they provide you with reacher experience)

See more on events [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)
A quote from this URL:

> The significant drawback with inline events is that unlike event
> listeners described above, you may only have one inline event
> assigned. Inline events are stored as an attribute/property of the
> element[[doc]](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Attributes/_Global#Event-handler_Attributes),
> meaning that it can be overwritten.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>How to clear localStorage on button click</title>
</head>

<body>

    <content>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Insert Data</legend>
            <input type="text" id="inpKey" placeholder="Insert Key.." />
            <input type="text" id="inpValue" placeholder="Insert Value.." />
            <button type="button" id="btnInsert">Insert</button>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Local Storage</legend>
            <ul id="outputList"></ul>
            <br />
            <button type="button" id="btnClear">Clear</button>
        </fieldset>
    </content>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        const printLSContent = function (el) {
            for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
                let key = localStorage.key(i);
                let value = localStorage.getItem(key);
                let li = document.createElement('li');
                li.innerHTML = `K: ${key}; V: ${value}`;
                el.appendChild(li);
            }
        }
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
            const inpKey = document.getElementById("inpKey");
            const inpValue = document.getElementById("inpValue");
            const btnInsert = document.getElementById("btnInsert");
            const outputList = document.getElementById("outputList");
            const btnClear = document.getElementById("btnClear");
            // element.addEventListener(event, handler[, options]); // type - event type; listener - event handler; options -
            btnInsert.addEventListener('click', function () {
                const key = inpKey.value;
                const value = inpValue.value;
                localStorage.setItem(key, value);
                location.reload();
            }, false);
            printLSContent(outputList);

            // //BUTTON CLEAR
            btnClear.addEventListener('click', function () {
                localStorage.clear();
                location.reload();
            }, false);
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```